# regex in Django urls.py

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

Help me please to fix urls.py 
People suggested this way, but it does't work for me.....

```
#urls.py
  (r'^/user/(?P<username>)/subject/([\w|\W]+)/$', subject),

#template
 {% for subject in subjects %}
    <li><a href="/user/{{ user.username }}/subject/{{ subject.name }}">{{ subject.name }}</a> {{ del_form.delete }}</li>
 {% endfor %}

#error
PAGE NOT FOUND
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/root/subject/Math%20140
....
....
^/user/(?P<username>)/subject/([\w|\W]+)/$
```

Comment: I don't know about django, but your regex requires the URL to end in a `/`, and your test URL (http://127.0.0.1....MATH%20140) does not end in a `/`. You could make it optional or remove it. Also, `[\w|\W]+` should be `[\w\W]+` since `|` doesn't mean anything in the `[]`. (Why not just do `.+` then? You are including new lines in `[\w\W]` whereas `.` does not)

Comment: To some extent, that also depends on whether or not the multiline flag (m) is set, which I don't think it is. A secondary issue might be that the URL is url-encoded, whereas the subject is probably not.

Comment: Django by default adds trailing slashes to URLs. The url-encoding issue would probably be best handled by adding a subject slug that doesn't include spaces etc, or using [the `slugify` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify) (and attempting to invert in the view - probably best to just add an actual [`SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) to avoid difficulties there).

Comment: @Dougal that's a nice suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an error in your regular expression. You should use a regex builder if you are new to this:

http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/ (Perl)

http://www.pyregex.com/ (Python)

I think you want something like this:

```
^user/(?P<username>.+)/subject/([\w|\W]+)/
```

But you might want to change the '.+' to something more restrictive:

```
^user/(?P<username>[^/]+)/subject/([\w|\W]+)/
```

Note also that you probably don't want that leading slash - due to the way Django feeds the initial URL to the URL dispatcher.